# Show childs when list member is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to do some kind of expand/collapse list with javascript. As far as I know, I did everything right but when I click list heading, I get

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

at the and of html code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Kaç Yakıyor?</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background-color:#CCC;
    }
    h1.header
    {
        font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        font-size:45px;
        font-style:oblique;
        font-weight:400;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div.content
    {
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:61%;
        background-color:#F00;
    }
    div.vehicles
    {
        margin-top:100px;
        width:17%;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#0F6;
        float:left;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    li.c
    {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    li
    {
        font-weight:normal;
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","123123") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("kacyakiyor");
    $query = "SELECT marka,model from arabalar";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
            <h1 class="header">KAÇ YAKIYOR</h1>
            <hr width="500px"/>
            <div class="vehicles">
            <h2><strong><em>Araba</em></strong></h2><hr/>
    <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<ul >";
                    echo "<li.c id='seen'><a href='#' onclick='show('hidden')'>".$row['marka']."</a>";
                        echo "<ul>";
                            echo "<li id='hidden'>".$row['model']."</li>";
                        echo "</ul>";
                echo "</ul>";       
            }    
    ?>
            <h2><strong><em>Motosiklet</em></strong></h2><hr/><br/></div>
            <div class="content">asdfasfda</div>

    <?php
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(id){
            var hiddenElement = document.getElementById(id);
            if(hiddenElement.style.display == 'none')
            {
                hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else
            {
                hiddenElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I get the error right after this but I don't see any extra "}".

```
<div class="content">asdfasfda</div>
```

Comment: instead of the PHP page, can you share the generate html

Comment: what is li.c by the way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
 echo "<li.c id='seen'><a href='#' onclick='show('hidden')'>".$row['marka']."</a>";
```

To

```
echo "<li.c id='seen'><a href='#' onclick='show(\"hidden\")'>".$row['marka']."</a>";
```

**UPDATE**

One thing i noticed is that you are using element id inside a loop which will generate multiple elements with the same ID. you can't have more than one element with the same ID so it's better to use class and select them by their class name.

Comment: Hmmm. I think this might be my solution. I tried your suggestion, it shows childs.When I clicked the second header, it shows first header's child but I think I can handle this.(Of course I don't say no to your suggestions to this problem). Thanks anyway.

Comment: i guess it's because you are using ID, if you are using row javascript my guess is that once the button clicked u need to select the parent and from the parent 'seen' as class you should be able to select the child ul. Good luck.

Comment: I couldn't manage to do what you said. In fact, I realized that when I put an alert method and tried to look which list item is clicked, no matter which one I click it says first one is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery children](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
    $("li.c a").click(function(){
    var children = $(this).children();
    if(children.filter(":visible").length > 0)
    children.hide();
    else children.show();
//or do something you like
    });
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

P. S.: li.c - did you mean `li class='c'`?

You may also use [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) for similar purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in escaping quotes in javascript.

Change this onclick from

```
onclick='show('hidden')'
```

to

```
 onclick='show(\"hidden\")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what the other posters have said, you need to change this line:

```
echo "<li.c id='seen'><a href='#' onclick='show('hidden')'>".$row['marka']."</a>";
```

to

`echo "<li id='seen'><a href='#' onclick='show(\"hidden\")'>".$row['marka']."</a>"`;
the

The only other thing I can think of - does your data include a } in it. You might have to do a `htmlentities($row['marka'])`